# Only run the innermost for loop in parallel

Tags: python, linux, bash

Here is my bash code.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#aggrs=(gcnconv gatconv sageconv ginconv)
aggrs=(gcnconv)
datasets=(HGBn-ACM HGBn-DBLP HGBn-Freebase HGBn-IMDB)
models=(homo_GNN relation_HGNN mp_GNN)
#models=(homo_GNN relation_HGNN)
ran=(1 2)
for aggr in ${aggrs[*]}; do
  for i in ${ran[*]}; do

    yaml="yamlpath: ${aggr}_${i}.yaml"
    echo ${yaml}
#    python space4hgnn/generate_yaml.py -a ${aggr} -s ${i}
    for dataset in ${datasets[*]}; do
        for model in ${models[*]}; do
        {
        para="-a ${aggr} -s ${i} -m ${model} -d ${dataset} -g $1 -t node_classification"
        echo ${para}
#        python run.py ${para}
        }&

      done
    done
  done
done
wait
```

There are many for loops in my code, but I only want to execute the innermost for loop in parallel.  But I found that the output is all executed in parallel.

output:

```
yamlpath: gcnconv_1.yaml
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m homo_GNN -d HGBn-ACM -g -t node_classification
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m mp_GNN -d HGBn-ACM -g -t node_classification
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m relation_HGNN -d HGBn-ACM -g -t node_classification
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m homo_GNN -d HGBn-Freebase -g -t node_classification
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m mp_GNN -d HGBn-DBLP -g -t node_classification
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m homo_GNN -d HGBn-DBLP -g -t node_classification
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m relation_HGNN -d HGBn-DBLP -g -t node_classification
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m relation_HGNN -d HGBn-Freebase -g -t node_classification
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m mp_GNN -d HGBn-Freebase -g -t node_classification
yamlpath: gcnconv_2.yaml
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m homo_GNN -d HGBn-IMDB -g -t node_classification
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m relation_HGNN -d HGBn-IMDB -g -t node_classification
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m mp_GNN -d HGBn-IMDB -g -t node_classification
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m homo_GNN -d HGBn-ACM -g -t node_classification
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m relation_HGNN -d HGBn-ACM -g -t node_classification
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m mp_GNN -d HGBn-ACM -g -t node_classification
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m homo_GNN -d HGBn-DBLP -g -t node_classification
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m relation_HGNN -d HGBn-DBLP -g -t node_classification
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m mp_GNN -d HGBn-DBLP -g -t node_classification
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m homo_GNN -d HGBn-Freebase -g -t node_classification
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m relation_HGNN -d HGBn-Freebase -g -t node_classification
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m mp_GNN -d HGBn-Freebase -g -t node_classification
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m homo_GNN -d HGBn-IMDB -g -t node_classification
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m relation_HGNN -d HGBn-IMDB -g -t node_classification
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m mp_GNN -d HGBn-IMDB -g -t node_classification
```

Obviously the code in the outermost for loop is also executed in parallel

I wonder if there is a way to execute only the code in the innermost for loop in parallel?

The output may be like this：

```
yamlpath: gcnconv_1.yaml 
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m homo_GNN -d HGBn-ACM -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m mp_GNN -d HGBn-ACM -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m relation_HGNN -d HGBn-ACM -g -t node_classification  
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m mp_GNN -d HGBn-DBLP -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m homo_GNN -d HGBn-DBLP -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m relation_HGNN -d HGBn-DBLP -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m relation_HGNN -d HGBn-Freebase -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m mp_GNN -d HGBn-Freebase -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m homo_GNN -d HGBn-Freebase -g -t node_classification
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m homo_GNN -d HGBn-IMDB -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m relation_HGNN -d HGBn-IMDB -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m mp_GNN -d HGBn-IMDB -g -t node_classification 
yamlpath: gcnconv_2.yaml
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m homo_GNN -d HGBn-ACM -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m relation_HGNN -d HGBn-ACM -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m mp_GNN -d HGBn-ACM -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m homo_GNN -d HGBn-DBLP -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m relation_HGNN -d HGBn-DBLP -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m mp_GNN -d HGBn-DBLP -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m homo_GNN -d HGBn-Freebase -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m relation_HGNN -d HGBn-Freebase -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m mp_GNN -d HGBn-Freebase -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m homo_GNN -d HGBn-IMDB -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m relation_HGNN -d HGBn-IMDB -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m mp_GNN -d HGBn-IMDB -g -t node_classification
```

Is there any solutions? Or Are there other ways to achieve the result I want?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `wait` afer innermost for loop :

```
for model in ${models[*]}; do
   {
   para="-a ${aggr} -s ${i} -m ${model} -d ${dataset} -g $1 -t node_classification"
   echo ${para}
   python run.py ${para}
   }&
done
wait
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry ,the output maybe like this:

```
yamlpath: gcnconv_1.yaml 
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m homo_GNN -d HGBn-ACM -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m mp_GNN -d HGBn-ACM -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m relation_HGNN -d HGBn-ACM -g -t node_classification  
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m mp_GNN -d HGBn-DBLP -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m homo_GNN -d HGBn-DBLP -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m relation_HGNN -d HGBn-DBLP -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m relation_HGNN -d HGBn-Freebase -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m mp_GNN -d HGBn-Freebase -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m homo_GNN -d HGBn-Freebase -g -t node_classification
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m homo_GNN -d HGBn-IMDB -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m relation_HGNN -d HGBn-IMDB -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 1 -m mp_GNN -d HGBn-IMDB -g -t node_classification 
yamlpath: gcnconv_2.yaml
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m homo_GNN -d HGBn-ACM -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m relation_HGNN -d HGBn-ACM -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m mp_GNN -d HGBn-ACM -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m homo_GNN -d HGBn-DBLP -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m relation_HGNN -d HGBn-DBLP -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m mp_GNN -d HGBn-DBLP -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m homo_GNN -d HGBn-Freebase -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m relation_HGNN -d HGBn-Freebase -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m mp_GNN -d HGBn-Freebase -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m homo_GNN -d HGBn-IMDB -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m relation_HGNN -d HGBn-IMDB -g -t node_classification 
-a gcnconv -s 2 -m mp_GNN -d HGBn-IMDB -g -t node_classification
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Only run the innermost for loop in parallel

Just:

```
for dataset in ${datasets[*]}; do
    for model in ${models[*]}; do
       para="-a ${aggr} -s ${i} -m ${model} -d ${dataset} -g $1 -t node_classification"
      echo ${para}
   done &
done
```

> The output may be like this：

Running in parallel is not synchronizing the output. You could:

```
for dataset in ${datasets[*]}; do
    for model in ${models[*]}; do
       para="-a ${aggr} -s ${i} -m ${model} -d ${dataset} -g $1 -t node_classification"
      echo ${para}
   done > "${dataset}_output.txt" &
done
 ....

for dataset in ${datasets[*]}; do
   cat "${dataset}_output.txt"
   rm "${dataset}_output.txt"
done
```

That way the output will be *synchronized*.